# Unable to retrieve value added to req object via middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, apollo-server

I have my server configured thus:

```
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { typeDefs, resolvers } from './schema';
import playgroundSettings from './playground.json';
import isAuth from './middleware/isAuth';


// GraphQL: Schema
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: {
    endpoint: '/blog', /* populates the playground endpoint box below the tab-strip. */
    settings: playgroundSettings,
  },
});

// Express: Initialize
const app = express();
// Middleware: isAuth
app.use(isAuth);
// Middleware: GraphQL route
server.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  path: '/',
});
// Express: Listener
app.listen(process.env.GRAPH_BLOG_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port: ${process.env.GRAPH_BLOG_PORT}`);
});

// Exports
export default app;
```

This is a GraphQL implementation using Apollo Server 2.0 and ExpressJS. However, as you can see, I'm using a custom middleware to perform some authorization tasks before hitting the GraphQL route. This middleware is named `isAuth.js` and gets called and executed as expected. However, I'm somehow unable to retrieve the properties this middleware adds to my req object from the resolver. The middleware looks like this:

```
// isAuth.js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  let decodedToken;
  const authHeader = req.get('Authorization');
  if (!authHeader) {
    req.isAuth = false;
    return next();
  }
  const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
  if (!token || token === '') {
    req.isAuth = false;
    return next();
  }
  try {
    decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.GRAPH_BLOG_JWT_SECRET);
  } catch (err) {
    req.isAuth = false;
    return next();
  }
  if (!decodedToken) {
    req.isAuth = false;
    return next();
  }
  req.isAuth = true;
  req._id = decodedToken._id;
  return next();
};
```

And when I do a `console.log(req);` in my resolver, I expect properties like `isAuth` and `_id`, but get the following instead:

```
{ _extensionStack:
   GraphQLExtensionStack {
     extensions: [ [FormatErrorExtension], [CacheControlExtension] ] } }
```

What's going on?

Comment: I am not sure about GraphQL, But one other way to pass custom variables across middlewares is to use `res.locals`. You might want to use `res.locals.isAuth` and `res.locals._id`

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the context line as shown below:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: {
    endpoint: '/blog', /* populates the playground endpoint box below the tab-strip. */
   settings: playgroundSettings,
 },
 context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res })
});
```